# Laravel: Validation unique when update and create

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, validation, unique

I have a Request with rules where I validate that one field is unique.

When I use:

```
'cod_upb' => 'required|max:10|unique:equipos,cod_upb,'.$this->id,
```

It works in the create method because it doesn't allow me to repeat the field in the database. But when I try to update it says that the field already exist or is taken.

Then I tried with:

```
'cod_upb' => 'required|max:10|unique:equipos,id,'.$this->id,
```

Which works on the update, but it let me create new items repeating the field.

How can I fix that?

Comment: My primary key is a field named "id" and it is an auto increment field in mysql

Comment: What does $this->id represent?

Answer (score 2):

In [Unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique) Rule

> unique:table,column,except,idColumn

3rd param is for `value for column to except` and 4th is for `column to except`

I am also using one validation method for both `insert` and `update` like this way

```
public function validateItems($requestAll){
    $id = isset($requestAll['id']) ? ','.$requestAll['id'].',id':'';
    $rules = [
        'cod_upb' => 'required|max:10|unique:equipos,cod_upb,'.$id,
    ];
    return Validator::make($requestAll, $rules);
}
```

Just change code for `$requestAll['id']` as I took for `id`, in your case it might be `$this->id`

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the unique on update wrong. You are checking it against the id field instead of the cod_upb field. 
`$this->id` should be renamed to something like `$equiposId`. Make sure `$this->id` is the id representing the `equipos` record in the database.

Change this:

```
'cod_upb' => 'required|max:10|unique:equipos,id,'.$this->id,
```

To this:

```
'cod_upb' => 'required|max:10|unique:equipos,cod_upb,'.$this->id,
```

On laravel 5.5

```
'cod_upb' => Rule::unique('equipos')->ignore($this->id),
```

Read more about this in the Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Please also add `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;` to use `Rule::unique` and add comment to make value of `$this->id` of 4 param in update and 2 param in insert

Comment: When I do what you mention it works on the create function but it doesn't work on the update. In the update it keeps saying that cod_upb already exists, which i assume is not ignoring the id

Comment: @MariaCamilaCuadrado What exactly is in $this->id ?

Comment: @C2486 if you ever developed with Laravel before or you are developing with Laravel at the moment this is common knowledge. And i have no idea what you are trying to say about the `$this->id` comment

Comment: @tprj29: OP is already using like as you suggested `'cod_upb' => 'required|max:10|unique:equipos,cod_upb,'.$this->id,` she is saying it is working for `insert` but not `update`, but yes the second suggestion `Rule` would work. for the `common knowledge` it is many things are common but people are still gets stuck.

Comment: To ignore `id` while updating it should be like `$id = isset($requestAll['id']) ? ','.$requestAll['id'].',id':'';` as I suggested.

Comment: @c2486 I think op is using the wrong id. On insert this isn't a problem because there is no other record with the exact `cod_upb` but on update the id that is ignored is incorrect and this will cause a problem because there is already a record with the `cod_upb`. This would make sense but OP should clarify what `$this->id` represents. The whole ignoring id on insert etc. is not the question but you make a valid point if you want to reuse the validation logic you should find out if you should add id yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

For create:

`public function controllerName(Request $request, $id)`

{

```
$this->validate($request, [
        "form_field_name" => 'required|unique:db_table_name,db_table_column_name'
    ]);

    // the rest code
```

}

For Update:

`public function anotherControllerName(Request $request, $id)`

{

```
$this->validate($request, [
        "form_field_name" => 'required|unique:db_table_name,db_table_column_name,'.$id
    ]);

    // the rest code
```

}

That's it. Happy Coding :)